# Partial Digest Problem(PDP) in python only spits out "None"

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Partial Digest Problem is one of the algorithms for getting the places of cut in DNA. Given all the possible lengths of cut, for example [2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,10] I have to figure out a way to find the actual places of cut. In this example total length of the DNA is 10, and the places of actual cut are [0,3,6,8,10].

[image: an introduction to bioinformatics algorithms]

From the algorithm above, I'm trying to build the actual code in python, and with hand I'm not sure what I've done wrong. 
The desired output for this code is
[0,3,6,8,10]
where I'm only getting
"None"
Can anyone please tell me what part in my code is wrong?

```
# function to remove multiple elements given as list
def delete(elements,A): 
    for el in elements:
        A.remove(el)
    return A

# y is given as integer, X as list
def delta(y,X): 
    n = len(X)
    for i in range(n):
        X[i] -= y
        X[i] = abs(X[i])
    return sorted(X)

# If former contains latter, return true. Else, return false
def contains(small, big):
    for i in range(len(big)-len(small)+1):
        for j in range(len(small)):
            if big[i+j] != small[j]:
                break
        else:
            return True
    return False

def partialDigest(L):
    global width
    width = (max(L)) 
    delete([width], L) # Needs to be in list to feed to 'delete' function
    X = [0, width]
    X = place(L,X)
    return X


def place(L,X):
    if len(L) == 0: # Baseline condition
        return X
    y = max(L)

    if contains(delta(y,X),L): # If former is the subset of L
        delete(delta(y,X), L)  # Remove lengths from L
        X += list(y) # assert that this y is one of the fixed points, X
        X = sorted(X) # To maintain order
        print(X)

        place(L,X) # Recursive call of the function to redo the upper part
                       # If none of the if statements match the condition, continue

        X.remove(y) # If the code reaches down here, it means the assumption that
                        # y is one of the points is wrong. Thus undo
        L += delta(y,X) # undo L
        L = sorted(L)   # To maintain order

    # Do the same thing except this time it's (width-y)
    elif contains(delta(width-y,X),L): 
        delete(delta(width-y,X), L)
        X += list(width - y) 
        X = sorted(X) 

        place(L,X) 

        X.remove(width-y) 

        L += delta(y,X) 
        L = sorted(L)


L = [2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]
X = partialDigest(L)
print(X)
```

Comment: `place()` returns `None`. Have `place()` return something to assign to `X` in `partialDigest()`.

Comment: Also see https://gist.github.com/marcoscastro/258e976bd2932624178c for a working iterative (rather than recursive) implementation of the same.